# Rotate a simple line in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, ios7.1, bezier

I drew two lines using bezier path, they look like the following:

```
________________

________________
```

What I want to accomplish is to rotate the second line. But I can't seem to get it right. 
Here's what I've done so far.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
//Path #1
UIBezierPath *p1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[p1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
[p1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250.0, 100.0)];
[p1 closePath];
p1.lineWidth = 15;
[[UIColor greenColor]setStroke];
[[UIColor redColor]setFill];
//draw the path
[p1 fill];
[p1 stroke];

//Path #2
UIBezierPath *p2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[p2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 200.0)];
[p2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250.0, 200.0)];
[p2 closePath];
p2.lineWidth = 15;
[[UIColor blueColor]setStroke];
[[UIColor yellowColor]setFill];
[p2 fill];
[p2 stroke];
CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);

}
```

It draws the lines but it doesn't rotate the second one.

Thanks.

Comment: You're aware your call to `CGContextRotateCTM` comes after your call to `stroke`?

Comment: I tried moving it around, if I move it before `[p2 fill]` or in between fill and stroke; then the line doesn't show at all.

Comment: That's because the line is now off screen. You're rotating the frame of the view, not just your line. What result do you want?

Comment: I want the second line to show vertical not horizontal

Comment: Rotated about what? Its center? Its left side? Why not draw it vertical in the first place?

Comment: Rotated from its origin pointing down. I could just draw it vertical but later on I have to deal with rotating shapes, so I wanna get a good idea how it works.

Comment: dont rotate the CTM. fix your path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what you're doing, try this. Cut out a piece of paper the size of the view on the simulator. Comment out your rotation line, run the app, and trace the line where it shows up in its unrotated position. Now, uncomment the line (but make the rotation M_PI/4.0) and run the app again -- you should see the line partially off the left side of the screen pointing down at a 45 degree angle. Now, holding the left top corner of the paper fixed at the top left corner of the simulator view, rotate the paper 45 degrees clockwise -- the traced line should now overlap the line on the screen. This is what you're doing when you do that rotation (BTW you want to use M_PI/2.0 if you want a 90 degree rotation not M_PI).

To get the line to rotate from its left edge, you need to translate the view but its x and y coordinate, then do the rotation, then translate back,

```
//Path #2
UIBezierPath *p2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[p2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 200.0)];
[p2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250.0, 200.0)];
[p2 closePath];
p2.lineWidth = 15;
[[UIColor blueColor]setStroke];
[[UIColor yellowColor]setFill];
[p2 fill];

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 100, 200);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI/2.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -100, -200);
[p2 stroke];
```

As Matt said in his answer you can apply the transfer directly to the bezier path instead of to the coordinate space. That's probably a better approach, and is conceptually easier to understand, I think. In the paper example I gave above, you'll notice that the only point that doesn't change its position on rotation is {0,0}. So, if you want to rotate a bezier path, translate it so the point you want to remain fixed is at {0,0}, rotate it, then translate back. Functionally, that just means you translate by the negative of the x and y coordinate first (instead of the positive with my original answer). So, for your example, that would be,

```
//Path #2
    UIBezierPath *p2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [p2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 200)];
    [p2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250.0, 200)];
    p2.lineWidth = 8;
    [[UIColor blueColor]setStroke];

    [p2 applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, -200)];
    [p2 applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];
    [p2 applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 200)];

    [p2 stroke];
```

Notice also, that your fill doesn't work, because a line (as a mathematical concept) has no interior, so there's nothing to fill -- the width of the stroke does not affect that. If you want a fill, then you should draw a rectangle not a line (there's no need for the closePath call either since there's nothing to close with a line).

Comment: Does that code actually work for you? Applying `CGContextTranslateCTM` etc. _after_ drawing isn't going to accomplish anything, I'd have thought...

Comment: Also this is a bezier path. You can transform it directly (`applyTransform:`). You have a funny mix of bezier path and current context that I'm not understanding.

Comment: @matt, yeah the stroke should be after the transform -- that was a copy and paste mistake. As far as using applyTransform:, I tried that and didn't get it to work. I'm investigating why.

Comment: @rdelmar I used your code and it works, thanks for the in-depth explanation. It made sense when you mentioned that I was rotating the entire frame. Anyways, thanks again. I find it difficult to get help from the Apple Developer documentation, so this is one of my only resources being a noob.

Comment: @matt. Yeah I tried the code and it works, it was just the [p2 stroke] that was out of the place. thanks.

Comment: @Alex, I updated my answer using Matt's suggestion, which is the way you should probably go.

Answer (score 1):

The way to apply a transform to a bezier path is with `applyTransform:`. You can do this before or after constructing the path, but you should do it before stroking/filling the path since at that point the path has been copied into the current graphics context. You should drop the whole business with getting the current context and applying the transform to that; you're just confusing yourself.